# AttributeError: 'socket' object attribute 'send' is read-only

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcpclient

I started reading the book "Black hat python" and upon writing the very 1st TCP client example I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'socket' object attribute 'send' is read-only
```

The  code is as follows:

```
import socket

target_host = "google.com"

target_port = 80

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client.connect((target_host,target_port))


client.send = ("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n")

response = client.recv(4096)
```

print response

Where could the mistake be?

Comment: You're trying to assign to a method call. You instead want `client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n")`. Voted to close as a typo.

Comment: how come `print = ("hello world")` doesn't print anything?

Comment: @user253751 Was that a rhetorical question for the OP, or a legitimate question?